# Solaris BIND / VI - how to view special characters in a zone file?

Tags: dns, solaris, bind

I'm having some issues with a new zone file and I recall previously that I was prone to using some special characters somewhere that confused BIND.

Is anyone aware of a command that would show all the hidden characters in the zone file?

Answer (score 0):

ON - :set list
Off - :set nolist

Not to be confused with the exec command CTRL-Q -> set list you actually have to type in the colon.